# I want to sum NetAmount where PolicyNo='POL-01' how will i achieve this in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to sum NetAmount where PolicyNo='POL-01' how will i achieve this in xquery.
My XML :

```
declare context item := document {
    <root>
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail>  
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    </root>
    };
```

OUTPUT :

POL-01
300.00

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XQuery.

**XQuery**

```
declare context item := document {
    <root>
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail>  
    <StatementDetail>  
            <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>   
            <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>              
    </StatementDetail> 
    </root>
    };
    
    <root>
{
  for $x in ./root/StatementDetail[PolicyNo='POL-01']
  let $PolicyNo := fn:upper-case($x/PolicyNo)
  group by $PolicyNo
  order by $PolicyNo
  return <statement>
            <StatementDetail>{$PolicyNo}</StatementDetail>
            <NetAmountSum>{sum($x/NetAmount)}</NetAmountSum>
      </statement>
}
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <statement>
    <StatementDetail>POL-01</StatementDetail>
    <NetAmountSum>300</NetAmountSum>
  </statement>
</root>
```